# Maven deploy:deploy-file not found due to version/timestamp appended to jar

Tags: ant, maven, archiva

I'm having a problem using `deploy:deploy-file` with snapshots I'd like some advice on please.

I have 2 projects; 1) `Ant` based and 2) the other `Maven` based that consumes the jars of the other project via `Archiva`.

I've added a target to the `Ant` project to deploy snapshots on every successful build during our iteration.

The problem is the Maven project cannot find them because the name of the dependency has a `timestamp appended like so`:

```
someJar-1.0-20100407.171211-1.jar
```

Here is the Ant target:

```
<exec executable="${maven.bin}" dir="../lib">
  <arg value="deploy:deploy-file" />
  <arg value="-DgroupId=com.my.package" /><arg value="-DartifactId=${ant.project.name}" />
  <arg value="-Dversion=${manifest.implementation.version}-SNAPSHOT" />
  <arg value="-Dpackaging=jar" />
  <arg value="-Dfile=../lib/${ant.project.name}-${manifest.implementation.version}-SNAPSHOT.jar" />
  <arg value="-Durl=http://archiva.xxx.com/archiva/repository/snapshots" />
  <arg value="-DrepositoryId=snapshots" />
</exec>
```

I have a similar Ant target for releases and this works fine.

Other pure Maven projects which deploy snapshosts via `mvn deploy` work fine.

Does anyone know where I am going wrong?

Thank You

**Update**

Figured out the answer, see below.

Comment: Could you disable the timestamp addition? (http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/examples/disabling-timestamps-suffix.html)

Comment: Doesn't seem to work, looks like Archiva is ignoring that flag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out the answer.

In my Ant target I was deploying the file as you can see.  I also then did the same thing but with the -tests jar.

This resulted in 2 snapshots in Archiva, not the usual 1 has you'd expect if you did mvn deploy.

Therefore the non test dependency could not be found because the latest snapshot was the -test jar.

Would be great to know how to solve this problem.

see [Deploying non Maven based module src and tests jar to Archiva in a single transaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2606554/deploying-non-maven-based-module-src-and-tests-jar-to-archiva-in-a-single-transac)