# Deploying non Maven based module src and tests jar to Archiva in a single transaction

Tags: maven, archiva

Is it possible to use `Maven deploy:deploy-file` or similar to deploy your `main src jar snapshot` and the `test src jar snapshot` to `Archiva` so that it `results in a single entry?`

Currently I have an `Ant` project which has jars I want publishing to Archiva and here is how I am doing it:

```
<!--Main Src Jar-->

<exec executable="${maven.bin}" dir="../lib">           
  <arg value="deploy:deploy-file" />
  <arg value="-DgroupId=com.xxx.gt" />
  <arg value="-DartifactId=${ant.project.name}" />              
  <arg value="-Dversion=${manifest.implementation.version}-SNAPSHOT" />             
  <arg value="-Dpackaging=jar" />               
  <arg value="-Dfile=../lib/${ant.project.name}-${manifest.implementation.version}-SNAPSHOT.jar" />             
  <arg value="-Durl=http://archiva.xxx.com/archiva/repository/snapshots" />             
  <arg value="-DrepositoryId=snapshots" />
</exec>         

<!--Test Src Jar-->

<exec executable="${maven.bin}" dir="../lib">           
  <arg value="deploy:deploy-file" />
  <arg value="-DgroupId=com.xxx.gt" />
  <arg value="-DartifactId=${ant.project.name}" />              
  <arg value="-Dversion=${manifest.implementation.version}-SNAPSHOT" />             
  <arg value="-Dpackaging=jar" />               
  <arg value="-Dfile=../lib/${ant.project.name}-${manifest.implementation.version}-SNAPSHOT-tests.jar" />               
  <arg value="-Durl=http://archiva.xxx.com/archiva/repository/snapshots" />             
  <arg value="-DrepositoryId=snapshots" />
  <arg value="-Dclassifier=tests" />                    
</exec>
```

The above Ant script will result in `two` snapshots on `Archiva`, 1 with the `main src jar` and the other with the `test src jar`.

Using mvn deploy on a typical Maven project will group the artifacts together.

**Non Grouped Archiva Image**

Has a sanpshot entry per deploy:deploy-file command

[image: Non Grouped]

**Grouped Archiva Image**

Has a single sanpshot entry grouping src and tests jars.

[image: Grouped using mvn deploy]

[Here's my earlier post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2606106/maven-deploydeploy-file-not-found-due-to-version-timestamp-appended-to-jar) which will help explain how I got to this point.

If anyone knows how to solve this I'd appreciate it.

Thank You

Comment: Why don't you use maven directly without using Ant?

Comment: Ah oversight that you have non maven based project. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the maven-deploy-plugin has evolved a lot. Right now it is possible to deploy multiple files within a single execution. See http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/examples/deploying-with-classifiers.html for the description.